# using scalars with short-circuiting or

Tags: matlab, scalar, short-circuiting

For a BMI calculator we need to create in programming class, I need to make sure that the values of size and weight are insinde of a certain range of numbers.
Every time the program tells me that I can only compare scalars when using a short-circuiting or.
However, after doing some reseaarch, I found floats to be scalars as well, so now I wonder what I did wrong.

Here you have the code I wrote by now:

```
weight = input("please enter your weight in kgs: ","s");
str2double(weight)
while isnan(weight)
weight = input("please enter your weight in kgs: ","s");
str2double(weight);
end
height = input("please enter your size in meters: ", "s");
str2double(height)

h = isscalar(size)
w = isscalar(height)

while isnan(height) || height > 2.2 || height < 1.3
hight = input("please enter your size in meters: ","s");
str2double(height);
end
```

I already tried to compare the two floats by themselves, but that did not work either.
Then I did some research, which also does not help solving the problem.
I now also changed the Name of the variable "size" to "height", but this does not help.

Here is one example input/output:

please enter your weight in kgs: 70

ans =

```
70
```

please enter your size in meters: 1.87

ans =

```
1.8700
```

h =

logical

0

w =

logical

0

Operands to the logical AND (&&) and OR (||) operators must be convertible to logical scalar values. Use the ANY or ALL functions to reduce operands to
logical scalar values.

Comment: `size` is a very commonly used inbuilt function, use a different variable name. What is the actual verbatim error message you are getting? Please can you [edit] your question to include it, along with some example inputs you are testing

Comment: Please don’t edit comments like that into your post. You can comment under the question or the answer if you like, but generally upvoting (once you have the rep) and accepting a useful answer are the best way of giving thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Here, `height` is a string, an array of characters (not scalar):

```
height = input("please enter your size in meters: ", "s");
```

Here, you convert the string to double, but you don’t store the result anywhere. `height` is still an array of characters:

```
str2double(height)
```

You might want to replace this last line with

```
height = str2double(height);
```

Or, better yet, remove the `"s"` from the `input` call. MATLAB will evaluate what the user types, and so will return a double in your case (but if the user types “`[1,1]`” or “`'foo'`”, it will return an array or a string, so you will have to test for that).